# PyCharms Autocomplete is not working for objects returned by libraries

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm When i have object returned by libraries i expect some auto completion on possible Methods of that objects... 
I'm trying this code:

```
import cv2    
video=cv2.VideoCapture()    
video.release()
```

I expect "release" to be suggested to me- like in VS in c#...
How to make it work ? 
Or im just expecting to much ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cv2.VideoCapture()` return type is particularly opaque, so PyCharm can't get attributes of the `video` object without executing the constructor.

If you create a file named `cv2.pyi` containing:

```
class VideoCapture(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None: ...
    def release(self) -> None: ...
```

then PyCharm will suggest `.release` as a completion.  Check PEP 484 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for what the above is.

PyCharm comes with the stubs in typeshed (https://github.com/python/typeshed) which unfortunately doesn't include stubs for cv2.